# views are invisible after activity transition ends

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

i recently faced a pretty strange issue with activity transitions. I'm trying to make a slide in transition with exclusions, which are native status bar, native navigation bar and my custom bottom navigation bar. So i created piece of code based on documentation ([link here](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity)) which in most cases works pretty well, but sometimes all views in the activity have visibility set as View.INVISIBLE (i know that fact from Layout Inspector).

So, i have activity A and activity B. Then i'm navigating from activity A to B via startActivity(). When i click back on activity B sometimes transition works fine, but in some cases all views on activity A (except bottom navigation bar, which was excluded from transition) are set to View.INVISIBLE

My code:

Activity A :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);

    Transition slide = new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT);
    slide.excludeTarget(findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_bar), true);
    slide.excludeTarget(findViewById(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground), true);
    slide.excludeTarget(findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground), true);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(slide);
    startActivity(i,
            ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, createPairs()).toBundle());


private Pair[] createPairs() {
    Pair[] pairs = new Pair[2];
    pairs[0] = Pair.create(findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground), Window.STATUS_BAR_BACKGROUND_TRANSITION_NAME);
    pairs[1] = Pair.create(findViewById(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground), Window.NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND_TRANSITION_NAME);
    return pairs;
}
```

Activity B:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    final View decor = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decor.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            decor.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            Transition fade = new Fade();
            fade.excludeTarget(findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_bar), true);
            fade.excludeTarget(findViewById(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground), true);
            fade.excludeTarget(findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground), true);
            getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? I have the exact same thing on a Moto G with Android 7.0 when I go and come back from 2 different screens. All other screens using the same transitions work fine...

Comment: I just "found" the issue... It seems the transition framework doesn't like transitions that are too long (mine had a duration of 600ms and lowering it to 300ms fixed the issue). Also, I had a lot of issues with slide transitions in the past... Try to switch your transition to a fade transition to see if it fixes your problem. The activity transition framework in general is pretty buggy. If you want to do shared element transitions, I recommend building a one-activity app using fragments, unfortunately...

Comment: So, in my case i've just give up with my code above and some time later i build it again from scratch.  Anyways, i discovered that for some unknown reason one of the transitions was paused (TransitionListener.onTransitionPaused()) in his lifecycle when visibility issue apperas. I also faced problems when some activity was calling with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

Comment: Now i have transition defined in xml as transition resource and defined default enter transition in styles.xml. I let Transition Framework play enter transition backwards as exit transition